# Arredondar casas decimais Javascript

Tags: javascript

Ao fazer o calculo de 5.605,50 * 0.08(8%) o resultado fica `448.40000000000003`

Preciso arredondar esse valor de `448.40000000000003` para `448.44` que é o valor exato de 8% na calculadora...

se eu usar o `.toFixed(2)` ele fica `448.40`...

se eu usar o `parseFloat(valor).toFixed(2)` ele fica `448.4`

Comment: Aqui para mim esse calculo já está dando certo desde o inicio, acompanhe meu teste [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/60tap2Ln/).

Comment: Transforma o número com ponto que o resulto será correto: `5605.50 * 0.08` --> `448.44`